# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String error

Tags: java, eclipse

So i got a error in the following code at the line:

```
for (final String key : keySet)
```

I don't know what to do, please help. :C
Would be great if you answer

```
Config.log("Loading " + fileName);
final Properties props = new Properties();
   props.load(in);
   final Set keySet = props.keySet();
   // error here!
   for (final String key : keySet) {
       final String prefix = "width.";
       if (key.startsWith(prefix)) {
          final String numStr = key.substring(prefix.length());
          final int num = Config.parseInt(numStr, -1);
          if (num < 0 || num >= FontRenderer.charWidth.length) {
             continue;
          }
          final String value = props.getProperty(key);
          final float width = Config.parseFloat(value, -1.0f);
          if (width < 0.0f) {
             continue;
          }
      FontRenderer.charWidth[num] = width;
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: for (final String key : keySet) {

Comment: Well, as the error says, at some point you try to convert an object to a `String`. Probably forgot an `toString()`-method

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Look at comment, where OP had stated the line which produces the error. Added that to question.

Answer (score 0):

props.keySet() returns a set of Objects and your for-loop thinks it's dealing with keys of type String.

You need to manually cast the key to a String or use toString():

```
Config.log("Loading " + fileName);
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
final Set keySet = props.keySet();
for (final Object key : keySet) {
    final String prefix = "width.";
    if (key.toString().startsWith(prefix)) {
        final String numStr = key.toString().substring(prefix.length());
        final int num = Config.parseInt(numStr, -1);
        if (num < 0 || num >= FontRenderer.charWidth.length) {
            continue;
        }
        final String value = props.getProperty(key.toString());
        final float width = Config.parseFloat(value, -1.0f);
        if (width < 0.0f) {
            continue;
        }
        FontRenderer.charWidth[num] = width;
    }
}
```

Comment: aaand what I Have to do now

Comment: Substitute further usages of key with keyStr or simply change key to key.toString()

Comment: Alternatively you could also declare your set as a bunch of strings. Such as `final Set<String> keySet = props.keySet();` before your for-loop